# Use redundant data in database design when have multiple relation

Tags: design, php, database-design, mysql

In my web application users can submit their advertises and buy package for advertise (packages are used for priority of showing advertises)

Database schema is like this:

**Package: id, title, priority(integer)

**PackageDuration: id, package_id(fk), duration, title

**Advertise: id, title, content, ...

**Order: price, user_id, ...

**AdvertisePackage: advertise_id(fk), packageDuration_id(fk), order_id, startDate

to show advertises lists **witch is the most used query** in application, I should join these tables:

Advertise=>AdvertisePackage=>PackageDuration=>Package

**My question is** for performance and ease of query I want to add fields In advertise table: (priority-startDate-endDate)

is it Bad design to do so?

Answer (score 2):

It is bad practice to denormalize as you state.  Depending on your search criteria, any one of the four tables could be chosen by the query optimization routine.  If you are selecting on a `package` selected from a drop-down list, there should be no reason to add the `packages` table to the query as you can match the `package_id` in the `package_durations` table.

There may be reasons to migrate columns from one table to another.  If package duration (start_date, end_date) can be modified after orders have been taken, you may want to copy the duration to the order.   If the `priority` of a package can change, copy it to the `orders` table, otherwise leave it in the  However, migrating columns to simplify the query can lead to issues.

Although many modelling tools will default to `id` as the surrogate key name, I find it more useful to use a prefix based on the table name.  For example use `order_id` for the `orders` table (`order` is a keyword and should be avoided). Having an `order` table implies you have only one order, while `orders` implies more than one order.  It helps if your table and column names can be used in sentences that clearly state your intent.